# Validation message acess without for loop

Tags: php

I wanta to access direct `[0] => Please enter only spaecial characters.`,

> [0] => You cannot enter more than 1 character

. this validation message ,but without foreach loop. My demo code is..

```
    Array
(
    [CodeConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SeriesConcateCharacter] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Please enter only spaecial characters.
                        )

                    [NumberPaddingCharacter] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => You cannot enter more than 1 character.
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So please suggest appropriate solution.

Comment: ['CodeConfiguration'][0]['SeriesConcateCharacter'][0]

Comment: I want to access both validation messages without any for-each loop??

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access like this..

```
echo $yourarray['CodeConfiguration'][0]['SeriesConcateCharacter'][0];
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/138145)

**Tip:**

Just start from the top and go down until you reach your destination and keep numbering the routes.

**`EDIT :`**

> I didnt want to hard code value pass ['CodeConfiguration'] and
>   ['SeriesConcateCharacter'].

```
array_walk($yourarray['CodeConfiguration'][0],function ($v)  { echo($v[0])."<br>";} );
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/138187)

Comment: @Abhishek, There's no need to modify the answer , It will still work. See the demo in the answer.

Comment: I didnt want to hard code value pass ['CodeConfiguration'] and ['SeriesConcateCharacter'].

Comment: Then you have to use a `foreach` .

Comment: by any php function..??

Comment: @Abhishek, Updated the code with `array_walk` and also with a demo.

Comment: It worrk Perfect...Thanks sir.